# WIX Conditional Message on Exit

Tags: wix

I have a WIX installer which I need to also install the VC++ 2015 runtime executable.  I'm using the vcredist_x64.exe as opposed to the merge modules ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815579/wix-run-vcredist-x64-exe-on-install)). I can successfully launch the vcredist_x64.exe after my msi finishes installing my application by using a custom action... however, what I'd like to do is first check to see if the runtime files already exist.  If they do, then I'll just finish without running the vcredist_x64.exe.  Otherwise, I'll run the custom action to install the runtimes as well.

It took some digging, but I was able to find out that the 2015 runtimes have a registry key shown below:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64

with an *Installed* value of *1* if they exist.

So, in my .wxs file I have the following registry search:

```
<!-- Visual C++ 2015 x64 -->
<Property Id="VCREDISTRUNTIMES2015INSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="VCREDISTRUNTIMES2015SEARCH" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64" Name="Installed" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Now, what I'd like to do is show a message on my exit dialog which says that if the runtimes aren't detected, then it will launch an installer to install them upon exit.  Something like this:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 is Required. Installation will proceed on exit.">
  <Condition>VCREDISTRUNTIMES2015INSTALLED</Condition>
</Property>
```

However, this doesn't work.  I get an error on the conditional tag and the project wont build.  Assuming my registry search is setup correctly, can someone tell me how to properly add a conditional message on my exit dialog?  Thanks!

Comment: If you go this way (I'd use a WiX bootstrapper instead), make sure that the following scenario doesn't result in reinstalling the VC runtime. 1) Install your app. 2) Uninstall VC runtime. 3) Uninstall your app.

Comment: @TomBlodget I see what you're saying.  but, I tried your use case and it still seems to work fine.  If I install my app (with VC runtime), then uninstall the VC runtime, and then uninstall my app... it doesn't re-launch the the VC runtime installer on uninstall.  I kind of expected that it would, but it just uninstalled my app, and that was all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... but here goes.  It turns out that my registry search was just fine... but I needed to use "SetProperty" instead.  So, something like this:

```
<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" After="AppSearch" Value="The Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2015 is Required. Installation will now install run-time components that are required to run C++ applications built using Visual Studio 2015.">
  NOT VCREDISTRUNTIMES2015INSTALLED
</SetProperty>
```

Now, if the VCREDISTRUNTIMES2015INSTALLED is null (or false) then it will show the message on the exit dialog.  Otherwise, there will be no message shown.  Hope that helps.