# WIX merge c++ runtime

Tags: wix, windows-installer, visual-c++-runtime

I have merged msm for vs 2015 crt:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR" >
<Merge Id = "Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm" FileCompression = "yes" Language = "1033" SourceFile = "..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\external\\tools\\systemsetups\\merge_modules\\Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm" DiskId = "1" />"
</DirectoryRef>
<Feature>
<Feature Id="Complete" Title="Complete" Absent="allow" Level="1">
...
<MergeRef Id="Microsoft_VC140_CRT_x64.msm"/>
...
</Feature>
```

but I still receiving:

```
---------------------------
MyApp.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because mfc140u.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any ideas how to merge it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems Microsoft recommends you use one of the redist executables (`vcredist_x86.exe`, `vcredist_x64.exe`) [instead of the merge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=msvc-160) (see towards bottom) these days since the 2015 versions of the runtimes are [more complicated than before](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) and the merge modules are basically insufficient: "*There will not be a merge module for the Universal CRT*".

***UPDATE***: [How to install the exe binary VCRedist along with your MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67375780/129130).

This is fully explained by **Bob Arnson** in this answer: [Redistributables for deploying C++ exe developed with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592378/redistributables-for-deploying-c-exe-developed-with-visual-studio-2015-on-wind/34597936#34597936) (**must read link** - it is the answer, I just added this one to throw in some further links as well).

Also, I don't have the list of merge modules in front of me on this Linux box, but perhaps there is an x86 version that you need - you are installing the x64 version? Just checking - these bitness issues are driving us all crazy.

---

***Some Links***:

- [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
- [Walkthrough: Deploying a Visual C++ Application By Using the Visual C++ Redistributable Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deploying-visual-cpp-application-by-using-the-vcpp-redistributable-package?view=msvc-160)
- [Redistributing Components By Using Merge Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=msvc-160)

Comment: I found problem: Microsoft_VC110_MFC_x64.msm :)

Comment: This answer is correct but how do I get WiX to do this. The WiX doco only mentions merge modules and I am forced by other factors to use WiX.

Comment: I added a link above to another answer of mine with some links on Burn - the tool in the WiX suite which can create setup.exe launchers that - among other things - can run installers in sequence.