# How to disable msi installer logging in the system log

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created the msi installer for my software using the wix tool. I am using integration with Microsoft_VC140_CRT.msm.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="SystemFolder" DiskId ="1">
   <Merge Id="VC140_CRT" SourceFile="..." Language ="0"/>   
</DirectoryRef>
```

During installation on Win 10 x64, an error occurs and the installer cancels the changes made in the system. In this case, the installer marks in the system log a warning that the application attempted to install an earlier version of the protected file C: \ WINDOWS \ System32 \ ucrtbase.dll. Event ID 1030.

How to disable msi installer logging in the system log?

Comment: How on earth did that happen? Is this from the official merge module for the Visual Studio runtime? Or are you manually trying to overwrite a protected OS file?

Comment: The error does not happen because of integration with VC140_CRT. I just need to prevent the error in the system logging.

Comment: For the record: [Microsoft recommends you don't use merge modules to deploy this runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421050/wix-merge-c-runtime/51423249#51423249). And if you are trying to replace this file yourself then it will not work because it is a protected OS file. I am also not aware of any easy ways to disable that event logging for an event that is a normal Windows event (and not your own error).