# Installing VC_REDIST.X86 quietly using InstallShield Lite

Tags: installation, installshield, redistributable

I have been pulling out what's left of my hair trying to install software that requires a C++ redistributable (2017 x86) using InstallShield lite.
To start with, I define a prerequisite To include the C++ redistributable.  When a user attempts an install, the user interface always appears.  Now this is not a real problem however, if the redistributable was already installed`or there is a newer version then it will fail with a message that it has failed and it wioll ask the user if he wants to continue or abort the installation. If he selects continue, the software installs fine. This is not very user friendly.
This happens despite the correct command line switches being used i.e. /q /norestart.  If you do this at a command prompt manually, it operates as it should.  In other words it installs it, or fails because it is already installed but tells the user nothing.  This is the way it is supposed to work.
Now I tried doing this as a custom action at the end of the installshield script but then the install appears to hang on some machines and on others other errors.
Now the only clue that I can give, is that if I create an MSI installation, then it never prompts.  However with a setup.exe install it acts as above.  I have only been successful with the msi install if I am installing a 64 bit app.  Never with a 32 bit app.
Can someone guide me as to what I am doing incorrectly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***VCRedist***: This C / C++ runtime (in various versions and flavors) is a pain indeed. I decided to write something up a while back to try to summarize a few things:
>   **[Wix per user installer to detect the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638587/wix-per-user-installer-to-detect-the-visual-c-2015-redistributable)** (please skim at least - not great, better than nothing I hope - deals mostly with detecting the presence of the runtime).

---

***Merge Modules***: Does **Installshield Lite** support merge modules? If so, you can install the **VCRedist** using merge modules instead of the **`VCRedist_x64.exe`** file. This is insufficient for UWP applications (the universal CRT) as explained in these links:

- **[Redistributables for deploying C++ exe developed with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592378/redistributables-for-deploying-c-exe-developed-with-visual-studio-2015-on-wind/34597936#34597936)**
- **[WIX merge c++ runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421050/wix-merge-c-runtime/51423249#51423249)**

> Do read the links directly above - they are quick reads.

***Batch File***: Another option would be to keep the **`VCRedist_x64.exe`** file separate from your main setup and to zip up your MSI and the **`VCRedist_x64.exe`** in a ZIP archive and put an **`Install.cmd`** batch file in there which will install the VCRedist first and then your MSI file? Not too neat - one would have to admit. I think you can make a self-extracting archive that would automagically invoke it, but I haven't done that in ages.

Just a **mock-up batch file** from link below (untested):

```
REM 1. Install VCRuntime
vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /log "%temp%\Install_vc_redist_2017_x64.log"

REM 2. Install MSI
msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi /L*v C:\MySetup.log /QN
```

Not sure about security fixes and that kind of stuff. Run Windows Update afterwards?

***Security Fixes & Link to Download***: There have been so many security fixes for this runtime, and it is usually installed on most machines, that I would frankly just link to the download of the latest version and have people install it themselves as a pre-requisite rather than bundling an obsolete version in my setup, but that isn't really sufficient unless your package is for corporate use only (in which case they prefer to install their own runtimes with full control).

---

***Some Links*** (to find easily):

- [**Command lines to install and uninstall silently the VC++ 2017 Redistribuables**](https://www.itninja.com/software/microsoft/visual-c-redistribuable-2017/v14-1) (**`installation command lines, untested by me`**)
- [**The latest supported Visual C++ downloads**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) (please check)
- **[Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Resitributable Package (x86)](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=22110#entry62393)** (please do read this)
- [How to prevent vc_redist.x##.exe (VS2017) from ambiguously failing due to pending reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754585/how-to-prevent-vc-redist-x-exe-vs2017-from-ambiguously-failing-due-to-pendin)
- [Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project - include VC++ 2015 Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119157/visual-studio-2017-installer-project-include-vc-2015-redistributable)
- [There is always the WiX toolkit](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html)
- [Distributable Code for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (Includes Utilities, Extensibility, and BuildServer Files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2017-redistribution-vs)
- [Mailbag: How to perform a silent install of the Visual C++ 2010 redistributable packages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2010/10/20/mailbag-how-to-perform-a-silent-install-of-the-visual-c-2010-redistributable-packages/)

Comment: InstallShield Lite does support merge modules but there are none present.  Nor in the VS 2018 releases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for a comprehensive answer.  I am sure it will help a lot of people.  What I have found is that running vc_redist.x86 from the command line in quiet mode will indeed always work as it should.  In other words, if it is not installed, it will be installed.  If it is already installed or a later release is installed, it will just return with no complaints.  That is not the case using InstallShield Lite 2018 (same for all previous releases).
However, there is a simple solution to get it to work as I found out.  All one needs to do is to include the entry Hidden="1" in the behavior part of the PRQ file.  So there will now be an entry that looks like this:

```
 <behavior Hidden="1" Failure="4" Reboot="2"/>
```

This solves the issue.  It no longer runs separately from the installshield installer with it's own GUI but rather the messages now appear in the menus in  installshield and it operates exactly as if you ran it at the command line.  No more errors.